# Changing from a subplot, violin plot stops working?

Tags: python, matplotlib, violin-plot

I want to make a plot like the first subfigure here:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(9, 4))

# generate some random test data
all_data = [np.random.normal(0, std, 100) for std in range(6, 10)]

# plot violin plot
axes[0].violinplot(all_data,
                   showmeans=False,
                   showmedians=True)
axes[0].set_title('violin plot')
```

This code works but I just want the first subplot as a separate plot, so I change to plt.figure and remove the parts related to axes[1], but I can't get the violin plot to work anymore!
I have also tried a separate plot using `sns.violinplot` but it rotates the violin and plots them all on top of each other. Tips?

Answer (score 1):

For simple single plots it's often easier to use matplotlib's `pyplot` interface rather than the object-oriented interface. Some functions have different names between these interfaces, e.g. `plt.title()` corresponds to `ax.set_title()`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# generate some random test data
all_data = [np.random.normal(0, std, 100) for std in range(6, 10)]

# plot violin plot
plt.violinplot(all_data,
               showmeans=False,
               showmedians=True)
plt.title('violin plot')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you create a figure using `fig = plt.figure()`, you still need to create a subplot in this figure using [`add_subplot()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_subplot). You can do this as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9, 4))
axes = fig.add_subplot()

# generate some random test data
all_data = [np.random.normal(0, std, 100) for std in range(6, 10)]

# plot violin plot
axes.violinplot(all_data,
                   showmeans=False,
                   showmedians=True)
axes.set_title('violin plot')
```

This produces the following figure:

[image: violin plot in a single subplot]

Note that `fig, axes = plt.subplots()` is simply shorthand for the two lines above, and the default values for `ncols` and `nrows` are `1`, so you can simply remove these arguments from your original code and it will also work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 4))

# generate some random test data
all_data = [np.random.normal(0, std, 100) for std in range(6, 10)]

# plot violin plot
axes.violinplot(all_data,
                   showmeans=False,
                   showmedians=True)
axes.set_title('violin plot')
```